# Finding parameterization for exponential integrand

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, parametrization, line-integrals

I'm currently working on a practice problem for my Calculus III class:

> "Evaluate the line integral along the negatively-oriented closed curve *C*, where *C* is the boundary of the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, and $(1,0)$:"
> $$\oint_{c}^{}(e^{2x+y}dx) + (e^{-y}dy)$$

I know that the first order of business here is to break the integral into two (due to the addition) & find suitable parametric functions for the integrands, but I'm at a loss as to how to do that for exponentials such as these.

*Many thanks in advance for any help you might be able to offer!*

Comment: I would say ... find parametric equations for the curve $C$ [and not for the integrand].

Comment: Between (0, 0) and (0, 1), x = 0 and y =t, say. What is the integral along that edge in terms of t?

Comment: You can also use Green's theorem here

Answer (score 1):

Given the orientation is negative, we must traverse the curve in a clockwise fashion when viewed from above : i.e, you must first go from $(0,0)$ to $(0,1)$ vertically upwards along $\ x = 0$, then proceed towards $(1,0)$ along $\ y + \ x = 1$ and then move left towards $(0,0)$ along $\ y = 0$

Break the curve C into three parts $\ C_1, \ C_2$  and $\ C_3$, each representing the three paths described above, respectively.

For $\ C_1$, it can be parametrized as $\ r(t) = 0 \ i + t \ j$, where 0 <= $\ t$ <= 1. Note that this implies $\ x = 0$ and $\ y = t $.

The reason for this is obvious - if you travel along the $\ y$-axis, $\ x$ remains 0 throughout, while $\ y$ is directly proportional to $\ t$.

The formula for the line integral of a given vector field $\ F$ along a given curve $\ r(t)$ is:

$$ \int \ F \cdot \ r'(t) dt $$

Notice from the given expression that $\ F = e^{2x+y} \ i + e^{-y} \ j $ which, along $\ r(t)$, further equals $\ e^{t} \ i + e^{-t} \ j$.

Now, computing the line integral, we get:

$$ I_1 = \int_0^1 (e^{t} \ i + e^{-t}\ j) \cdot ( 0 \ i + 1 \ j) dt $$

$$ = \int_0^1 e^{-t} dt = \frac{e-1}{e} $$

Similarly, $\ C_2$ can be parameterized as : $\ x(t) = t, y(t) = (1-t)$ for $\ 0 \le t \le 1$  and $\ C_3$ can be parametrized as : $\ x(t) = t, \ y(t) = 0 $ for  $\ 0 \le t \le 1 $.

The rest is merely a matter of computation.

Comment: you can use \le and \ge instead of <= and >=

Comment: @SineoftheTime Okay. Thanks.

Comment: Small mistake, the $\hat\jmath$ component of $r'(t)$ is not $t$.